# How do I get rid of the "multiple describeType entries" warning?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

Does anyone know why when using BindingUtils on the selectedItem property of a ComboBox you get the following warning? Any ideas how to resolve the issue?

The binding still works properly, but it would be nice to get rid of the warning.

```
warning: multiple describeType entries for 'selectedItem' on type 'mx.controls::ComboBox':
<accessor name="selectedItem" access="readwrite" type="Object" declaredBy="mx.controls::ComboBase">
  <metadata name="Bindable">
    <arg key="" value="valueCommit"/>
  </metadata>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to override the property in question and declare it final.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code. It is basically a copy of BindingUtils.bindProperty that is setup for a ComboBox so that both the combo box and the model are updated when either of the two change.

```
public static function bindProperty2(site:Object, prop:String, host:Object, chain:Object, commitOnly:Boolean = false):ChangeWatcher
{
    var cbx:ComboBox = null;
    if ( site is ComboBox ) { cbx = ComboBox(site); }
    if ( host is ComboBox ) { cbx = ComboBox(host); }
    var labelField:String = "listID";
    
    var w:ChangeWatcher = ChangeWatcher.watch(host, chain, null, commitOnly);
    
    if (w != null)
    {
        var func:Function;
        
        if ( site is ComboBox )
        {
            func = function(event:*):void
            {
                var dp:ICollectionView = ICollectionView(site.dataProvider);
                var selItem:Object = null;
                
                for ( var i:int=0; i<dp.length; i++ )
                {
                    var obj:Object = dp[i];
                    if ( obj.hasOwnProperty(labelField) )
                    {
                        var val:String = String(obj[labelField]);
                        if ( val == w.getValue() )
                        {
                            selItem = obj;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                site.selectedItem = selItem;
            };
                
            w.setHandler(func);
            func(null);
        }
        else
        {
            func = function(event:*):void
            {
                var value:Object = w.getValue();
                if ( value == null )
                {
                    site[prop] = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    site[prop] = String(w.getValue()[labelField]);
                }
            };
            w.setHandler(func);
            func(null);
        }
    }
    
    return w;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't appear to be an answer to the question